# system monitor shows downloading while lsof -i says nothing downloading

Tags: networking, internet

when i checked system monitor it says there is something downloading but lsof -i showing nothing.

[image: Screen shot]http://i47.tinypic.com/1zqadm9.png

my ISP provider allows me to connect to a single host at a time. So simultaneous connections wont allow me to browse or anything.

when i do sudo lsof -i

```
    COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd      1   root   27u  IPv6  14623      0t0  TCP *:ipp (LISTEN)
systemd      1   root   28u  IPv4  14624      0t0  UDP *:ipp 
avahi-dae  932  avahi   12r  IPv4  16956      0t0  UDP *:mdns 
avahi-dae  932  avahi   13r  IPv4  16957      0t0  UDP *:50944 
httpd     1085   root    4u  IPv6  18759      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     1170 apache    4u  IPv6  18759      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     1174 apache    4u  IPv6  18759      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     1175 apache    4u  IPv6  18759      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     1179 apache    4u  IPv6  18759      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     1183 apache    4u  IPv6  18759      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     1184 apache    4u  IPv6  18759      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     1189 apache    4u  IPv6  18759      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     1192 apache    4u  IPv6  18759      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
mysqld    1253  mysql   10u  IPv4  19195      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
cupsd     1789   root    4u  IPv6  14623      0t0  TCP *:ipp (LISTEN)
cupsd     1789   root    5u  IPv4  14624      0t0  UDP *:ipp 
cupsd     1789   root   12r  IPv4  24001      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:ipp (LISTEN)
sendmail  2057   root    4u  IPv4  25935      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:smtp (LISTEN)
```

Comment: "my ISP provider allows me to connect to a single host at a time" -- I have never heard of such a ridiculous thing.  Even simple web browsing often connects to multiple hosts at the same time.  This would cause so many problems in so many common situations I can't believe it.  If this is really true, you need to fire those idiots and get a proper ISP.

Comment: Aircel india network! ... am using EDGE internet through GSM

Answer (score 2):

Possible that something's running in the background under a different user? You'll find the output of `lsof -i` and `sudo lsof -i` differ *dramatically*.

I would simply assume that something was running as as different user that System Monitor is showing (based on the raw device throughputs) that non-root `lsof` doesn't have permission to see.